# Find the Nearest Two Dimensional Points from two lists of data. Discard unused points

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following data.

```
x1coord = Sort@RandomReal[{-2, 25}, 270]; y1coord = Sort@RandomReal[{-2, 25}, 219];

x2coord = Sort@RandomReal[{0, 27}, 280]; y2coord = Sort@RandomReal[{0, 27}, 224];

dataSet1 = Table[{x1, y1}, {x1, x1coord}, {y1, y1coord}];  
dataSet2 = Table[{x2, y2}, {x2, x2coord}, {y2, y2coord}];
```

I need to find nearest points of `dataset1` and `dataset2`. Nearest point mean {x1, y1} to {x2, y2} so taking account of both point (not just the x or y in isolation). Note dataset2 has more points, any points left over in dataset2 can be discarded.  The points discarded could be at either end of the list (low or high numbers).

Where the letters a, b etc indicate the nearest paired points.

So I need

```
DataSet3 = { {{x1a,y1a}, {x2a, y2a}}, {{x1b,y1b}, {x2b, y2b}}, .......etc}}
```

I am still using *Mathematica* 9, but plan to upgrade soon.

Comment: Have you seen [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest.html)? Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: `{#, First@Nearest[dataSet2, #]} & /@ dataSet1`

Comment: note it can happen that a given elements of set 2 is `Nearest` more than one point in set1.  You need to specify how to handle that. I think this is a dup per Summit, in any case.